# Why did the Mars population flee to Earth if they had the Soul Cube?

Tags: video-games, doom, doom-3

Somehow, I think I missed a bit. The old civilization that was uncovered by UAC on Mars, apparently escaped to Earth after accidentally (just like the UAC) opening the Hellgate with their teleportation technology.

However, The Doom Guy/The Marine only managed to defeat the Cyberdemon because he previously found the Soul Cube, an artifact that was left behind by the ancient civilization on Mars.

[image]

I'm not sure if I may be mixing up the Doom film and the Doom 3 plot, but I think both statements hold for the Doom 3 story.

My point is, why would the old Martians have to flee to Earth if they had the Soul Cube, which was "wielded by their mightiest warrior"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the final battle (no telling how long the war waged for) against the demons left Mars unable to support life.

From [Doom wiki](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Doom_3):

> The few Martians buried their warrior along with the Soul Cube and
>   the stone tablets to alert anyone of the dangers of the misuses of
>   their technology. Since Mars become a desolate planet, they fled to
>   other planets - including Earth.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a canon answer for this, but given the themes of your enemies being corrupted humans, it is possible that their "mightiest warrior" was corrupted. It is also reasonable that you, the doom guy, are the mightiest warrior who just wasn't born yet.

Comment: No, we encounter the tomb of their warrior in the caverns; From Doom Wikia: "*With it, their single greatest champion, simply called "the Hero", (a take on the Doomguy's namelessness) took on the invading force singlehandedly and managed to seal the portal. "The Hero" didn't seem to survive since his burial chamber was found. He appears to be very tall, because his tomb is very long.*" He *did* defeat the hellforces.