# What is the origin of the Heart-Artifact?

Tags: doom, doom-3

In *Doom 3: Resurrection of Evil* our (new) fearless protagonist finds a new artifact shaped like a human heart (it effectively replaces the Soul Cube in function).

[image: Heart artifact in the hands of our Marine]

We know that the Soul Cube was [manufactured](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15736/2565) by the ancient Mars civilization, but that the strange heart-shaped artifact must have some strong connection to Maledict's three main demons.

What is its actual origin? Who created it and was it once an actual living heart?

Answer (score 1):

Initially designed to aid the forces of Hell but captured by the Ancient Martians during Hell's first invasion, also known as the **Heart of Hell** and the **Bloodstone**.

[This Wiki page](https://doom.wikia.com/wiki/The_Artifact) gives further details.

Comment: It's been a while but the answer could probably use a bit of fleshing out now; how about editing in some of said "furtehr details"? :)